# How to use env variable which is set in a child process in the path to the called shell script

Tags: bash

I am calling a shell script from java code using process builder class.
In this,the path to the shell script is : `/{ENV_VARIABLE}/idm_migration/oim/bin/mySrcipt.sh`.

Before calling `processbuilder.start()`, I have set the env variable `ENV_VARIABLE` as `/u01/myPath`.

But when the script is getting started, it is not taking the value of the `ENV_VARIABLE` as set by the code.
Here is the code :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder (new String[]
{"$ENV_VARIABLE/idm_migration/oim/bin/OIMV2Migration.sh");

Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("ENV_VARIABLE", "/u01/myPath");

Process p = pb.start();
```

How to call the script using this env variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke the script after creating a shell environment. There could be other ways to do this, But this works for me. Try this -

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder ("/bin/bash", "-c", "$ENV_VARIABLE/idm_migration/oim/bin/OIMV2Migration.sh");
```

Comment: I tried this only , but when the script is getting called using pb.start() , the ENV_VARIABLE's value in the path to the script is the one that has been set initially in the shell env and not the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that we can use the environment variable "$ENV_VARIABLE" while giving the entire path to the script ("$ENV_VARIABLE/idm_migration/oim/bin/OIMV2Migration.sh") because the environment variable has not been set for this child process yet.

By doing the way I was doing , the value of the "$ENV_VARIABLE" set in the path of the script will always be fetched from the System environment and not from the child process's environment.